# How does an std::unordered_set avoid potential page faults on every element in iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

Or does it?

To clarify: in an `std::vector` if during iteration an element is accessed that is not currently on a page cached into memory there is a page fault and that page is loaded but then the next `k-1` elements are guaranteed to be cached into memory where `k` is the number of elements that fit on a memory page.

It seems to me that in a hash table data structure like `std::unordered_set`, during iteration, there is no guarantee at all that for any element accessed, subsequent elements will be anywhere close to it in memory, meaning under generative conditions with a large number of elements you could have a potential page fault for every element accessed during iteration. Am I wrong about this? If so by what method does `std::unordered_set` use to prevent this?

Just curious. I am outlining an algorithm I plan on implementing right now and am trying to wrap my head around how it would preform with limited memory and a lot of elements under degenerate conditions and my incomplete knowledge regarding how `std::unordered_set` works under the hood is a limiting factor here.

Comment: *"by what method does `std::unordered_set` use to prevent this?"* It generally doesn't attempt to. In practice, you would have to be extremely unlucky, or your machine extremely short on memory, to get a page fault for every element.

Comment: Actually just loaded page with that `vector` element might get unloaded back to page file and accessing next item on the same page will lead to another page fault. Basically most of C++ application deal with this simply by delegating real memory management to system assuming that memory allocated with language means is accessible.

Comment: Define unlucky for me. Lets say I WANTED to sabotage an unordered_set and make it as slow as possible for some significantly large n number of elements. Would there be a way to do this (possibly something like constantly inserting and deleting elements randomly with an only slightly higher chance of insertion until I got n elements, or by deleting large sequences of contiguous elements, etc.) or is it just a probability thing that is completely independent of what I do to the set?

Comment: Provide a custom `operator new` that implements a heap that scatters allocations across as many physical pages as possible. Then put heavy memory pressure on the system to force it to thrash.

Comment: "if during iteration an element is accessed that is not currently on a page cached into memory there is a page fault " - on some architectures, but not on others, which have no concept of pages or page faults. So, this is not addressed by C++.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem for the allocator than `std::unordered_set`, provided your hash function isn't awful

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. `std::unordered_set` is implemented using a hash table, with *separate chaining*. That is, there is a linked list for every bucket, which grows to store the items of the bucket. This means that as you iterate through, bucket by bucket, you have to dereference pointers to dynamic memory each time, and risk a cache miss.

If you wanted something similar which uses contiguous memory and so avoids page faults while iterating, you could use a hash table with *open addressing*. For instance you could use linear probing, or use something like cuckoo hashing. But you'd have to implement these yourself or use someone else's non-standard container library. These kinds of maps and sets  can't quite be done in a way that respects the iterator invalidation requirements of the standard maps and sets.

Answer (score 1):

Both unordered and ordered associative containers necessarily suffer from discontiguity of referenced memory.

I wrote "necessarily", because the C++ standard insists that pointers and references to elements in associative containers remain valid as long as the element is not removed from the container. This makes impossible certain techniques fie improving locality of reference which would require moving elements to improve memory layout.

Memory dispersion does not just (or even principally) cause excessive paging. The most apparent consequence is usually decreased memory cache utilisation, which can significantly increase run time. (Obviously excessive swapping also has an enormous impact, but if you memory us that restricted, you will run into problems regardless of hash table reference locality.)

Cache-aware algorithms do exist, but there are several reasons why they are not often used:

1. The optimisation is only useful  in some very specific use cases.
2. It is hard to write a cache-aware algorithm without knowing quite a lot about the data being hashed. General-purpose library functions, which are expected to work with any datatype, rarely bother to provide optimised specialisations for specific datatype.
3. The reference-stability of standard associative containers is extremely useful in a large number of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unordered list can be thought of as a vector (keyed by the hash of the key), with a linked list of similarly hashed elements.

An iteration through the unordered list iterators the vector (sharing the same page fault pattern), and then the linked list.  If there are no items sharing a slot, it will have the same read pattern as a vector.

As it is unordered, this iteration is a random view of the data.